# Charset in XAMPP Apache Server

Tags: php, mysql, apache, character-encoding

I got some issues with my Apache server from XAMPP for running PHP, I included the following in my PHP files to set their charset to the following:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
```

I want to display the german special characters ä, ö, ü and ß. But all I get displayed are some strange letters.

Does anyone know how to solve this? Change the charset of the apache server maybe? 
I would be glad if anyone could help me figuring this out?

Yours,
Tim

Answer (score 0):

I suggest your try using the charset UTF-8 instead:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Or if you're developing for HTML5, you can use this shorter version:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: Tried this but it doesn't work. Still displaying special characters with those strange question tags...